# Nested variable getting incorrectly incremented

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

// Data
class cat {
  constructor(name, picture, clicks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.picture = picture;
    this.clicks = clicks;
  }
};

var cat1 = new cat('Mercury', 'cat1.jpg', 0);
var cat2 = new cat('Venus', 'cat2.jpg', 0);
var cat3 = new cat('Mars', 'cat3.jpg', 0);
var cat4 = new cat('Jupiter', 'cat4.jpg', 0);
var cat5 = new cat('Saturn', 'cat5.jpg', 0);
var cat6 = new cat('Neptune', 'cat6.jpg', 0);

var cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5, cat6];


// Program
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
  // Current cat
  var icat = cats[i];

  $('#cat_list').append('<li id="cat' + (i + 1) + '">' + icat.name + '</li>');
  $('#cat' + (i + 1)).on('click', (function(iSaved, icatSaved) {
    return function() {
      console.log('You clicked on cat' + (iSaved + 1) + ' from the list!');
      $('#cat_title').text(icatSaved.name);
      $('#cat_image').attr('src', 'img/' + icatSaved.picture);
      $('#catClicks').text(icatSaved.clicks);
      $('#cat_image').on('click', function() {
        icatSaved.clicks++;
        $('#catClicks').text(icatSaved.clicks);
      });
    };
  })(i, icat));
};
```

It works great except for the embedded click handler that increments the click count for the cat object in question.  It seems that the click incrementing ends up impacting more than one of the cat objects and also causes some of them to increment by 2, 3, or 4 when clicking on the picture.  I must be doing something dumb to get this behavior but I'm not sure what.  Is this because I’ve embedded a click handler within the list click handler?

–Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting an event listener inside another event listener. Each time `#cat{N}` get clicked, you add another event listener for `#cat_image`. Thus clicking it over and over again setup more and more event listeners for the same element. When you click `#cat_image`, all those event listeners get invoked, and since they are all incrementing the `clicks` property, the latter get incremented a lot of times by just one click.

The best way at approaching this is to use event delegation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
    var icat = cats[i];

    // add a class of .cat and a data-index attribute to all cats
    $('#cat_list').append('<li class="cat" data-index="' + i + '">' + icat.name + '</li>');
    //                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};


var catSaved = null;                              // move this outside the event listener to be visible for both event listeners
$('#cat_list').on('click', '.cat', function(e) {  // whenever a .cat element get clicked from within #cat_list element
    var index = $(this).data('index');            // get the index of that cat from cats array (previously stored in data-index)
    catSaved = cats[index];                       // get the cat itself

    $('#cat_title').text(catSaved.name);
    $('#cat_image').attr('src', 'img/' + catSaved.picture);
    $('#catClicks').text(catSaved.clicks);
});

$('#cat_image').on('click', function() {          // move this event listener outside, to set it only once
    if(catSaved) {                                // if we have a catSaved element
        catSaved.clicks++;                        // ...
        $('#catClicks').text(catSaved.clicks);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  I couldn't see it, but now that you explain it that makes complete sense.  I like your approach - I don't completely understand this yet, but I have some good material to learn about it.  This seems less complicated than my approach.